# Vectors-Can anyone explain me the concept of sense in vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

Is it same as the direction? Then, why another term "sense"is used, instead of direction? Can anyone illustrate it?

Comment: I know that there's a difference in French: "direction" would be the east-west axis, for example, and "sens" would be either east or west. I don't think that's the case in English (both "sens" and "direction" are translated to "direction"). Do you speak French, or are you reading a French book, by any chance?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: We make this distinction in Dutch (and I suppose German) as well. ("zin" and "richting").

Answer (score 3):

Some people would say that the vectors $v$ and $-v$ have different directions. One direction is the negative of the other; the vectors are not parallel, they are anti-parallel.

Other people would say that $v$ and $-v$ have the same direction (and that they are parallel). These people would then say that $v$ and $-v$ have different "sense".

The first group of people don't need the word "sense"; the second group do need it.

You can't use the word "sense" instead of the word "direction". You always need the word "direction", but, if you belong to the second group of people mentioned above, you also need the word "sense" to clarify.